# Color points in in openlayers3

Tags: openlayers-3

How can I change the standard blue color and size of points in openlayers 3?
I do like this:

```
while (lats.length > 0) {
            var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
                source: new ol.source.Vector({
                    features: [
                        new ol.Feature({
                            geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lons.shift(), lats.shift()], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
                        })
                    ]                    
                })
            }); 
            map.addLayer(layer);
        }
```

If I add styles then either nothing changes, or everything does not work. How to add styles here?

Answer (score 0):

this is answer:

```
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
            //create empty vector
        });

        var styleGreen = new ol.style.Style({
            image: new ol.style.Circle({
                radius: 7,
                fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                    color: 'green'
                })
            })
        });

        while (lats.length > 0) {
            var iconFeature = new ol.Feature({
                geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.transform([lons.shift(), lats.shift()], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'))
            });
            vectorSource.addFeature(iconFeature);
        }       

        var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: vectorSource,
            style: styleGreen
        });

         map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```